# WerFault.exe Forcing current window focus In and out. Need to kill it

Tags: windows-10

I have a horrible problem. Randomly today, everything on my windows 10 computer goes in and out of focus. Every application. It's taking me awhile to type because chrome goes in and out, and its not counting keystrokes since it's not "active" when not focused. I tried downloading a program that shows me what is currently taking over the current focus, I ran It. It shows me:

```
4376:C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe | Wed Nov 30 23:57:58 2016
7100:C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WerFault.exe | Wed Nov 30 23:58:01 2016
4376:C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe | Wed Nov 30 23:58:01 2016
3224:C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WerFault.exe | Wed Nov 30 23:58:05 2016
4376:C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe | Wed Nov 30 23:58:05 2016
```

That is the Windows Error Reporting service. WerFault.exe.
It will not go away.

Here's what I've tried:

- Going through services, disabling the startup of WerFault, stopping Werfault.
- Following with a reboot.

Somehow its still taking over, and it's driving me crazy. I have to write a speech today, and this stack question is difficult enough. Someone please help me slaughter this program. I don't care about the consequences of turning it off. Thank you so much!

**EDIT**: Nothing is crashing according to WER and reliability monitor. Just tell me how to stop WerFault. I've been at this for 3 hours.

**EDIT 2** Nothing in eventlog either, I just want to know how to stop WerFault. My desktop is unusable at this point. I've considered a fresh install of Windows but that's ridiculous when I know I can do something as simple as keeping a windows service ( one that I dont even want) turned off. I'm not asking for suggestions, I'm asking how to disable WerFault.exe.

Comment: this means some apps wer crashing. fix the issue (XY problem: asking for x (disabling werfault instead of asking y - how to fix the crashes)

Comment: I should pointed out that nothing is crashing.

Comment: sure, if you see this right after chrome, a chrome process / plugin is crashing. look in eventlog for more details about which tools crash

Comment: No. It's with every application. Chrome is the one that was in focus (becuase I was trying to type. All that reporting is just whats currently in focus), and WerFault was stealing it. I could use notepad and I'd get the same thing but with notepad instead of chrome.

Comment: again, look in eventlog for crashes

Comment: Again, nothing in eventlog, nothing anywhere. I am merely asking for someone to explain how to terminate WerFault for good.

Comment: same problem here, for me the cause seems to be nvcontainer.exe (as shown in Event Viewer/Windows Logs/Application).

Comment: @magicandre1981 Irrespective of what crashes, WerFault should not steal focus!  In my case it's the synaptics driver that crashes, do you expect me to "fix" it, as in decompile it, fix it, and compile it back?  Sheesh!

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem and was looking for ways to prevent WerFault.exe from stealing focus. It turns out I had error logs in the Windows Logs > Application section in Event Viewer.

For me it was an application called MicTray64.exe that was continually logging an error and then straight afterwards Windows Error Reporting would log some info.

The fix in my case was to delete the app that was causing the error as it was unnecessary and I didn't want to troubleshoot the program in question.